# How to define placeholders/slots in grand parent and inject component from child?

Tags: reactjs

In many programming languages - eg. go and c# razor you have the ability to define placeholder / areas (layouts) which you can inject content into from other templates/views.

I know in some frontend frameworks this is also possible eg. aurelia where you define slots. I also found this library https://github.com/dschnare/react-slot and https://github.com/monvillalon/react-page-layout which doesn't seem like it is actively maintained.

Then I found this: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html which seem to do something similarly except it goes the wrong direction. Here the parent will have to know about the child, since you pass it in from the parent.

Instead I'd like to just define a placeholder in the parent, which I can reference from the child, and somehow insert a grand child into.

Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Hope it makes sense. How can this be done in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need slots. You can achieve this with a state and a conditional rendering.

For the different pages rendering i recommend [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).

As for the "slot" for the settings button you can just use a condition to render it.

Here is a running snippet with a very simple example:

```js
const PageOne = ({ showSettings }) => (
  <div>{!showSettings ? <h1>Page 1</h1> : <div>Settings Page</div>}</div>
);
const HomePage = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;

const ButtonPageOne = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}>Button for Page 1 only</button>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPageOne: false,
      showSettings: false
    };
  }

  togglePages = () => 
    this.setState({ showPageOne: !this.state.showPageOne });
    
  onSettingsClick = () =>
    this.setState({ showSettings: !this.state.showSettings });

  render() {
    const { showPageOne, showSettings } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Some header</h3>
          <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
            {showPageOne && <ButtonPageOne onClick={this.onSettingsClick} />}
          </div>
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.togglePages}>togglePages</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        {showPageOne ? <PageOne showSettings={showSettings} /> : <HomePage />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I conditionally rendered the elements, of course you can conditionally pass some `CSS` classes or `styles` instead.

The key point here is that you should [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), let the parent manage the state that some sibling children needs to know about (or use a state manager like [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/) for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However I guess I wasn't clear enough. The important part is that the settings component is located inside the page1 component, and is triggered by the ButtonPageOne if the current page has a settings component. So the key point is that the settings component will overlay it's parent (page1) when the ButtonPageOne is clicked in the global header. Your answer, while great, is only addressing the button in the header.

Comment: You mean like a modal window?

Comment: Yes kinda like a modal (it'll just overlap the div once activated), but with fields/settings defined explicitly for page1 etc. Ideally this should not be defined in the parent, but rather in the child

Comment: It's definitely working exactly as I need it to now, but still there's a problem. Ideally there would just be a placeholder for the ButtonPageOne - a slot to define it's placement. And then from within the page 1 component, this slot could be populated with the button, if the page1 component itself had a settings component inside it. This is pretty easy to do in razor in c#, golang, aurelia, vue etc and is usually a common way to build flexible layouts. I find this way to be a lot more hardcoded instead of dynamic :/ Local state is not a requirement - actually I'm using MST for state mgmt.

Comment: children should  know **nothing** about their parents nor siblings. this way your child component "needs" a parent that support a settings button. that would make the child component not much flexible.

Comment: although you might be right, it is common practice in other languages / frameworks, so I'll leave this question open for a while to see if somebody can come up with a solution.  Here's a good example of what I'm trying to do: https://github.com/monvillalon/react-page-layout - but i was hoping there'd be a more react-ish way to achieve this, instead of having to resolve to an old abandoned repo which few people uses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use callback props to get this to work, though I would advise against it.

On the parent, define a function called `showSettingsIcon` that takes a boolean parameter and pass it to the child as a prop. The child would have logic to determine whether it has a settings child and call the function. Make sure the function is "bound" to the parent, just like you would any other callback prop.

You could have another callback prop, `setGrandchildComponent`, or something, that would take a component instance or component type as a parameter. When called, the parent would save a reference to the parameter and clone it or create an instance of it in `render()`.

But, if you did something like this, you would be messing up the ["Unidirectional Data Flow"](https://hashnode.com/post/why-does-react-emphasize-on-unidirectional-data-flow-and-flux-architecture-ciibz8ej600n2j3xtxgc0n1f0) that makes React so powerful. By passing data and commands up and down, your app becomes less deterministic and harder to reason about. As your app becomes more complex, it's really hard to reproduce tricky bugs and add new features.

If you really *really* need this kind of functionality, I would suggest looking at a state management library like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/). A warning, though: They have a pretty significant learning curve.

I recently migrated a project to use Redux with React, because I wanted cool features like you describe. I had written myself into an uncomfortable corner. It's so much better to work with the philosophical grain of any library/framework than against it.

Comment: I already use MST for state management, so local state and passing props is not a limitation.